# what design pattern to use for different base object procedures

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I would like to write a library which can be extended.  Here is a rough code outline:

```
class Object
{
    ActionProc* pAP;
};    
class Sphere : public Object;
class Point : public Object;

class ActionProc
{
    virtual Action( Object* ) = 0;         
};

class ActionProcMove : public ActionProc
{
    bool m_bCanMove;     

    virtual Action( Object* obj )
    {
        if( m_bCanMove )
        {
             //do some moving stuff
        }
    }; 
};
```

And a user of this library might extend it like so:
(again, just a code outline)

```
class ActionProcSize : public ActionProc
{
    bool m_bCanSize;     

    virtual Action( Object* obj )
    {
        if( m_bCanSize)
        {
             //do some sizing stuff
        }
    }; 
};
```

Although this would work, it would mean I would have to create a make a procedure-object for each object-object I create. Instead I would prefer to create just one procedure-object for all objects who will need that type of procedure.

Or in other words, I need a place to store the extra variables needed for the procedure linked to the object.

*Please note, this isn't actual code, just an example*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid adding ActionProcs with default behavior, you could point to a global (hopefully stateless) ActionProc with this behavior.  You can overwrite for inherited classes and overwrite by passing an ActionProc in the constructor for non-default behavior.

BTW: your code resembles GOF's [bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) design pattern.

Comment: its more like i want to be able to direct to the ActionProcs instead of adding them and the problem is that they have a state

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "to direct to the ActionProcs instead of adding them", but since they have state, there seems reason to add them.

Comment: by directing i mean multiple objects who have the same pointer so in that way they actually direct to the same object. Instead of like it is now, they also direct to the actionprocedure but each object has it own.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider storing the state in the Object itself.

```
class Object {
  std::map<UINT32 id, bool variable> mBoolStates;
  std::map<UINT32 id, UINT32 variable> mUINTStates;

  ActionProc* pAP;
};
```

Then the user can add the states is wants to the object and retrieve them in their Action class instances. (There might be a better way to provide a collection of states).